# Yoneda extensions and $\operatorname{Ext}$ functor.

Tags: homological-algebra, derived-categories

I am reading this this entry http://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/06XU of the Stacks Project.

I'm having problems in understanding how $\left(L^{-i+1}\oplus A\right) / L^{-i}$ is constructed. I mean, which map are we using to construct the cokernel?

I guess $f$ should be used in the proof but they don't mention anything.

Comment: A map $f:L^\bullet\rightarrow A[i]$ is simply a map $f:L^{-i}\rightarrow A$ such that $L^{-i-1}\overset{d}\rightarrow L^{-i}\overset{f}\rightarrow A$ is zero. The cokernel $(L^{-i+1}\oplus A)/L^{-i}$ is the cokernel of the map $d\oplus f$.

Comment: Thanks!  I don't know why I was so blind!